# Create Subfolders using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Ok, looking for some assistance with Powershell. I need to create a subfolder with the same name in about 200 folders in a directory. So far I have this:

```
$folder = NewFolderName
new-item -type directory -path \\servername\directory\directory\$folder -Force
```

Will this work to create the single folder in all 200 folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code snippet:

```
$parent = '\\servername\directory'
$folder = 'NewFolderName'
Get-ChildItem -Path $parent -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Item -WhatIf -Type Directory -Path (
            Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath $folder) -Force
    }
```

Remove the risk mitigation parameter [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7#whatif) no sooner than debugged…